# Convert string to int before querying django ORM

Tags: python, django

I have a model

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    maca = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

This field will accept only numbers (cannot set char field to integer field for business reasons)

Now I have to get all entries that have maca greater than 90

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
Entry.objects.filter(maca__gte=90)
```

But get isn't working because the maca is a string.

How can I convert maca to int before filtering? Or something like this?

Thanks

Comment: Not able to test it right now but maybe [cast](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.Cast)? - `annotate(maca_num=Cast('maca', output_field=IntegerField()).filter(maca_num__gte=90)?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```py
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models import IntegerField
Entry.objects.annotate(maca_integer=Cast('maca', output_field=IntegerField())).filter(maca_integer__gte=90)
```